# Why does a hive table need to be bucketed to support ACID transactions?

Tags: hive, acid

I'd like to know why a hive table needs to be bucketed to support ACID transactions. Is it just some hive quirk? Or was there a reason behind it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something about hive's compactor:

> The compactor runs background MapReduce jobs to compact the delta and
>   base files. There are two types of compaction: major and minor.  The
>   minor compaction merges many small delta files into one big delta
>   file. The major compaction is more expensive, it takes delta files and
>   merges them with the base files. All merging happens by creating a new
>   file and removing the old ones. There is a special cleaning process to
>   do so. **The compaction is done for each bucket separately. Base and
>   Delta files are created per bucket.**

More here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions

So, the more buckets, the faster the compaction.